Uno platform/MVUX: using a template selector that binds a class-specific page to each item in a ListView
I am trying to display objects of different classes (with a common interface) in a ListView. I would like to use a specific Page to visualize each class of objects. I have implemented a template selector that correctly chooses the view for each type of object, but I am using event handlers for ComboBox objects inside these views, and when the event handler is called, the object attached to DataContext is the object itself instead of the bindable proxy object.
This is what I have:
In ReportEditorModel.cs:
public IListState<IReportItem> ReportItems => ListState<IReportItem>.Empty(this);

In ReportEditorPage.xaml:
<Page.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ReportItemTableModel" x:Key="TableTemplate">
    <local:ReportItemTablePage/>
  </DataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ReportItemNumberModel" x:Key="NumberTemplate">
    <local:ReportItemNumberPage/>
  </DataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ReportItemTextModel" x:Key="TextTemplate">
    <local:ReportItemTextPage/>
  </DataTemplate>
  <local:ReportItemTemplateSelector x:Key="ReportItemTemplateSelector"
      TableTemplate="{StaticResource TableTemplate}"
      TextTemplate="{StaticResource TextTemplate}"
      NumberTemplate="{StaticResource NumberTemplate}">
  </local:ReportItemTemplateSelector>
</Page.Resources>

In ReportItemTablePage.xaml:
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource PrimaryContainerColor}" CornerRadius="10" Background="{ThemeResource BackgroundBrush}" Margin="10">
  <StackPanel Spacing="4" Orientation="Horizontal" AllowDrop="False" Padding="10">

    <TextBlock Text="Table"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Tables}" SelectionChanged="OnSelectedTableChanged" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedTable}"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Types}" SelectionChanged="OnSelectedTypeChanged" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedType}"/>
  
  </StackPanel>
</Border>

Any idea how can I solve this problem? Is there any way to have the MVUX bindable models automatically attached to the items in the list?
Thanks in advance!
